# How do I bind my index finger movement read using webcam to cursor movement on screen?

Tags: python, pyautogui, mediapipe

I have the coordinates of my index finger that is read through a webcam. I am even able to convert them to frame coordinates. But I am unable to have the mouse respond properly to the movements. It just jumps to the right edge of the screen and sticks there.

I tried doing this using PyAutoGUI. I thought about multiplying the coordinates with the ratio of screen dimensions and frame dimensions.

This code triggers the failsafeCheck in PyAutoGUI.

```py
move_x = index_position[0] * (screen_width / frame_width)
move_y = index_position[1] * (screen_height / frame_height)
pyautogui.moveTo(move_x, move_y)
```

Changing from "moveTo" to "move" makes the mouse move extremely slowly and only to the right. Nothing on the left, up or down.

I also saw the one below being used in a tutorial so I modified it and tried it too.

```py
x1 = np.interp(index_position[0], (frame_reduce, image_width - frame_reduce), (0, screen_width))
y1 = np.interp(index_position[1], (frame_reduce, image_height - frame_reduce), (0, screen_height))

curr_loc_x = prev_loc_x + (x1 - prev_loc_x) / smoothening
curr_loc_y = prev_loc_y + (y1 - prev_loc_y) / smoothening
pyautogui.move(screen_width - curr_loc_x, curr_loc_y)
prev_loc_x, prev_loc_y = curr_loc_x, curr_loc_y
```

Edit: This works as a basic method but it will not actually follow my finger like I want it to.

```py
if hand_pose == "index finger":
    if zone == "left":
        pyautogui.move(-50,0)
    elif zone == "right":
        pyautogui.move(50, 0)
    elif zone == "top":
        pyautogui.move(0,-50)
    elif zone == "bottom":
        pyautogui.move(0, 50)
```

Comment: Stupid me forgot that I haven't converted the position into screen coordinates to save on unnecessary calculations. A small change to the first code and it now works.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre] (includes debugging done by you)